# Visual Studio 2008 sometimes resets Platform back to "Any CPU" from "x86"

Tags: visual-studio-2008, configurationmanager

I have a multi-project solution where I've set the Platform for all projects to "x86", using Configuration Manager.  It's set this way for both Debug and Release builds, in all projects.

Twice now, Platform has reset itself back to "Any CPU", and I've had to go into Configuration Manager again to fix it.

Today, it happened after I got a new working copy from Subversion, but I'm not sure if that's what happened the last time.

Any suggestions on why this might be happening, and how to prevent it in future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the selected build is a user preference, so if you check out a clean copy, you will start with a blank user pref. file. VS then would default to the first in the list, which is probably 'any cpu'.

Comment: Is what you call the "pref" file the file with the ".suo" extension?  Windows Explorer shows this as a "Visual Studio User Options" file - maybe I need to add this to SVN?  (Assuming I can get the other developer on my project to agree with my options)

Comment: No, you should not include the .suo in the svn, or else it creates the same problem (ie: always sets the build to whatever was set by the last person to commit). The solution is to keep your .suo file when you svn update or simply just set your build type everytime you checkout a clean copy. This is all assuming the selected build is in the suo file, let me double check...

Comment: Yes the only file that changes when you change your build is the .suo file, so that must be it. It is a binary file, so you can't change it easy (except for opening VS and changing the build setting :).

Comment: Even though this is the solution, this is terrible! We have a TFS build server, which builds our x86 EXE files incorrectly, so they sometimes run as x64 and our x86 COM components then fail. The build platform settings should NOT be a user setting, but a project setting, and should therefore be stored in the PROJECT file instead of the SUO file.  Shame on you Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a way to at least detect the problem when it happens.

Added the following to the Pre-build Event Command Line:

```
rem EXIT WITH ERROR 99 IF PLATFORM IS NOT x86. (CHECK CONFIGURATION MANAGER)
if $(PlatformName) NEQ x86 exit 99
```

If the Platform setting changes, I now get an error when I build the project.

Crude, but it works.